# Expand content to multilpe pages/views or a vertical scroll

Tags: java, android, scroll

I am developing a very basic app where where I need to have a large number of buttons on a page.The problem after a point only a limited no of buttons are displayed on a page ..the rest are either out of the page or are disoriented.What I wish to do is like suppose if there are 50 buttons ,then I wish to display  25 buttons on one page,25 on the other page.
If this is not possible then atleast the buttons are not lost and i can access them using a scroll button or something.

I tried `<Scrollview>` but it was of no help.

Here is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >



    <TextView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:text="FUNNY SOUNDS"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55sp"
android:id="@+id/tv"
 />
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="8" >
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="History"
        android:layout_weight="2"
         android:background="@drawable/custom" />
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="History"
        android:layout_weight="2" 
         android:background="@drawable/custom"/>
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/b3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="History"
        android:layout_weight="2"
         android:background="@drawable/custom" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Go"
      android:layout_weight="2"
       android:background="@drawable/custom"/>
    </LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="8"
     >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Back"
        android:layout_weight="2" 
         android:background="@drawable/custom"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b6"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next" 
        android:layout_weight="2"
         android:background="@drawable/custom"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b7"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Refresh" 
        android:layout_weight="2"
         android:background="@drawable/custom"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b8"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="History"
        android:layout_weight="2"
         android:background="@drawable/custom"/>
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="8" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b9"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Back"
        android:layout_weight="2"
         android:background="@drawable/custom" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b10"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next" 
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@drawable/custom"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b11"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Refresh" 
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@drawable/custom"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b12"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="History"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@drawable/custom" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="8" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b13"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Back"
        android:layout_weight="2" 
        android:background="@drawable/custom"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b14"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next" 
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@drawable/custom"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b15"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Refresh" 
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@drawable/custom"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b16"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="History"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@drawable/custom" />
</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Sorry for the bad english if any further explain i will.Thank for any suggestions .How should i proceed with the problem.What should be the approach.

Comment: Why `ScrollView` was of no help? What have you tried with it ?

Comment: i tried `Scrollview` ,was able to get the scrollbar but the missing buttons were not displayed

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ScrollView` before each of your `LinearLayout`.

> Remember a ScrollView can be applied to only one View/Layout.

So you need to write it for all your layouts.

```
<LinearLayout
    ....>
    <ScrollView
        ...>
        <LinearLayout
            ....>
            <Button
                 android:id="@+id/b1"
                 ..../>
            <Button
                 android:id="@+id/b2"
                 ..../>
            <Button
                 android:id="@+id/b3"
                 ..../>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it works for you.